# ASP.NET MVC: run code after view has rendered (close db transaction)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I am using ASP.NET MVC2 with NHibernate, but am facing an issue. All calls to the database via NHibernate should be inside a transaction, however code inside the view kicks off database calls in some instances. Thus there is a need to be able to commit the transaction after the view has rendered.

For example displaying a list of users and their user roles you might show the user role using this code:  <%: Model.UserRole.Name %>

This will cause a hit on the database as the UserRole is loaded using a NHibernate proxy.

You can fetch the UserRole eagerly which circumvents the issue in this case, but there are cases where it is much faster to use lazy loading.

Anyway, is there a way to run code after the view has rendered?

Comment: I really don't understand why calling the object model will hit the db it beats the whole purpose of MVC. Can you provide some code from your controller?

Comment: He is correct: with lazy loading it will, but it's not a problem, it's a feature.

Comment: Even with the lazy loading, I feel we should not be doing anything in the View which will initiate a DB connection.  I would consider changing the design.

Comment: I agree ideally, however there are certain situations where you have no choice.

The way to get around this that works in most cases, is to use eager fetching. However, when you use eager fetching, SetMaxResults won't limit the results with SQL, since each single User for example will have multiple rows.

What it does is get all the Users that match the query, then just lop off those that aren't needed. So your query may return 100,000 users to the nhibernate code, the it returns you the top 2. This is much slower than just getting 2 and then using lazy loading to get the UserRole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an action filter?

```
public class CleanUpAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //cleanup code here
    }
}
```

Then you decorate your controllers with this attribute.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. I modified http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2009/09/03/asp-net-mvc-transaction-attribute-using-nhibernate.aspx to work this way.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use session-per-request pattern? It's a very natural way of handling NHibernate sessions in web environment.

There are many information available when you do a Google search on "NHibernate session per request", like [this blog post](http://hackingon.net/post/NHibernate-Session-Per-Request-with-ASPNET-MVC.aspx).

Also, take a look at great Bill McCafferty's article [NHibernate Best Practices](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx). Although it's written for NHibernate 1.2, it has a wealth of information. While there, his [S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) also looks very cool :)

Comment: Thanks, you also included what I need in your links.